# why some https website don't need ocsp query

Tags: ssl, https, ocsp

Would you tell me what the difference between these two https config。
thank you very much!

[don't need ocsp query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dulj8.jpg)

[need ocsp query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/641dd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

- OCSP is not mandatory: the certificate may only give CRL to check the revocation
- OCSP may be cached (the OCSP answer is valid for few days)
- OCSP may be stapled: during the tls handshake with the webserver, he provided a signed (by the CA) OCSP answer, to avoid that request.

Comment: thanks, Tom .   I used ocsp stapling on my website ,but need ocsp query every access. I'm very confused.

Comment: If you activate OCSP stapling on your server, your server will periodically contact the CA to get a signed OCSP answer, and when a client will connect to your server, your server will provide that OCSP answer, so the client doesn't need to ask it to the CA.